# How to get the "text-justify:kashida" css property effect on to the arabic text excluding IE browsers

Tags: html, css

I am using `<p>` tag for inserting Arabic text into the html page, and giving the CSS property `text-align: justify;` with particular width and height in pixels.

With this, there would be the paragraph including inconsistent space between the paragraph words; how can we use the same with proper word-stretching (with proper tatweel/kashida) inside the word?

I have tried it with the `text-justify: kashida` CSS property, but it's only working with IE, not for any other browser! As per the image shows, it is clear that the `text-justify: kashida` is not supported by Mozilla, and other browsers expect the IE.

[image]

How can I get the same behaviour in all browsers, to display the same as Internet Explorer?

Comment: Who'da imagined IE being the one to implement a standard and other browsers lagging behind.  :)

Comment: it is just the result i seen in to my investigation with, not a part of promoting or some imagination but strongly need to find some solution to this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately seems `kashida` is dropped from [CSS3 text](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/) and deferred for [CSS4 text](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-text-4/), so if you want justify your text with Kashida, you should try porting harfbuzz-old [adding kashida algorithm](http://cgit.freedesktop.org/harfbuzz.old/tree/src/harfbuzz-arabic.c#n336) (that its algorithm is removed from newer generation of harfbuzz, [ref](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/persian-computing/s-ftgmBvlF0/mhB2V9ELwwYJ)) which is based on a Microsoft specification that is archived [here](https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/Arabicdev/IE6/KBase.asp). Here is Microsoft's kashida insertion priority table that you should try to implement somehow:
[image]

ّAdding Kashida («ـ») for text styling on HTML itself is not a good idea (because if user copy the text it will contains added Kashidas and it will make problem for browsers find-in-page) however as current webkit[<sup>bug</sup>](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6148)/blink[<sup>bug</sup>](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6122) (Safari/Chrome) versions do not support joining cursive script characters (like Arabic/Persian) during inline ([pseudo](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/13/learning-to-use-the-before-and-after-pseudo-elements-in-css/))elements there seems there is not any chance you get this type of justification without inserting Kashida (or you should handle [oncopy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.oncopy) event by your own that has [its](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/CopyAndPaste.html) own problems).

It is also interesting that Microsoft is extended IE Kashida justification implementation to support more interesting things like [text-kashida-space](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms531173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (configure ratio of kashida to white space expansion while text justifying). Seems we must wait another decade to these get implemented across all major browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the details...at least we can conclude ourself for this rendering related issue.

Comment: New link which do not need retrieving from archive.org http://www.microsoft.com/middleeast/msdn/JustifyingText-CSS.aspx

Webkit related bug: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=6203

Comment: The used algorithm on OpenOffice: https://github.com/mirror/openoffice/blob/ac58ea25d9ea6e57181d6047264340cdc75de79a/main/sw/source/core/text/porlay.cxx#L1145 same with Microsoft one

Comment: Which predates to https://github.com/LibreOffice/core/commit/47eb4e01731d502ec9fd1c882222feb27bf47ce6

https://github.com/LibreOffice/core/commit/816bbd9835b20a7c87b3b788f522e23736f22b14#diff-df953a0cba0d686d3cd92dd78f73739fR175

Comment: Another intresting document http://quod.lib.umich.edu/j/jep/3336451.0013.105/--justify-just-or-just-justify?rgn=main;view=fulltext

Comment: Dropped from CSS4 also https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2014Apr/0321.html

Comment: Did anyone got it working using above information?? Or is it all hypothetical?

Comment: That depends, the libraries that should implement these are not yet, but LibreOffice/OpenOffice already use them.

Answer (score 2):

The `text-justify` property was implemented in IE, and it is not part of any completed CSS specification. It exists in the Working Draft [CSS Text Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/), but even there, it is marked as being at risk: “The following features are at risk and may be cut from the spec during its CR period if there are no (correct) implementations: [...] the ‘text-justify’ property, particularly its ‘kashida’ value”.

From the authoring perspective, the best you can do is to hope that other browsers will catch up. The styling requested is relatively complicated and probably not anything you can imitate with JavaScript in the same sense as you can “polyfill” CSS properties

Comment: Thanks for giving the sense of css working draft, i will check in to it. then in that case can you suggest any polyfill to get over this problem with crossbrowser compatibility.